# Fantasy, possibly children's book, with a main character named "Axle" who hunts dragons

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons, wizards

There's this novella/novel I read, probably in elementary or middle school, about a boy named Axle who hunts dragons throughout the book.

I remember that one of the other main characters was a quirky old wizard, a mentor character, who had a bad lisp due to his pet eating the letter 'S' during a spell gone wrong, and said wizard sometimes accidentally mentally slips into the future, presumably because of the same said spell(?). He slips into the future one time and spoils something to the main character unintentionally at one point.

I also remember vaguely that one of the dragons the boy defeats was killed by blowing it up from the inside while it breathed in. I also remember being weirded out by the concept somewhere in the book that the boy was already destined to be married to his girlfriend when they grew up one day, or something like that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this ***[Dragonslaying is for Dreamers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/711174.Dragonslaying_is_for_Dreamers)*** (2004) by Dave Marks, the first book in the *[Dragonslaying](https://www.goodreads.com/series/118181-dragonslaying)* trilogy...?

According to the Goodreads plot summary, the protagonist is named Axel and he meets a lisping wizard who teaches him how to kill dragons:

> In a world that never was and never will be, but as in our own world, every boy needs to be able to marry his girl, buy land and feel like a man, but this isn't always possible.
>
> The only way to be what he feels driven to be is for Axel to harvest dragons for bounty - huge and terrible beasts, which think, learn, and kill with pleasure.
>
> **Dream with Axel as he escapes the clutches of his small town, falls in love with beautiful Molly, meets the lisping wizard who teaches him how to kill dragons, and follow him on a quest for riches and manhood into his world's dark and dangerous caves.**
>
> Dragonslaying is for Dreamers is a rites of passage novel about a young man who must find a way to be recognized as a man and to be able to function as one in his society. It is written for children ages 10 through 15.
>
> [image: Front cover of "Dragonslaying is for Dreamers" (2004) by Dave Marks.]